# can I redirect the output of this program to script?

Tags: python, stdin

I'm running a binary that manages a usb device. The binary file, when executed outputs results to a file I specify.

Is there any way in python the redirect the output of a binary to my script instead of to a file? I'm just going to have to open the file and get it as soon as this line of code runs.

```
def rn_to_file(comport=3, filename='test.bin', amount=128):
    os.system('capture.exe {0} {1} {2}'.format(comport, filename, amount))
```

it doesn't work with subprocess either

```
from subprocess import check_output as qx
>>> cmd = r'C:\repos\capture.exe 3 text.txt 128'
>>> output = qx(cmd)
Opening serial port \\.\COM3...OK
Closing serial port...OK
>>> output
b'TrueRNG Serial Port Capture Tool v1.2\r\n\r\nCapturing 128 bytes of data...Done'
```

The actual content of the file is a series of 0 and 1. This isn't redirecting the output to the file to me, instead it just prints out what would be printed out anyway as output.

Comment: `os.system` -> `subprocess` ...

Comment: @user202729 doesn't look like that's working for me added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Windows, which has a special reserved filename `CON` which means to use the console (the analog on *nix would be `/dev/stdout`).

So try this:

```
subprocess.check_output(r'C:\repos\capture.exe 3 CON 128')
```

You *might* need to use `shell=True` in there, but I suspect you don't.

The idea is to make the program write to the virtual file `CON` which is actually stdout, then have Python capture that.

An alternative would be `CreateNamedPipe()`, which will let you create your own filename and read from it, without having an actual file on disk.  For more on that, see: [createNamedPipe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319679/createnamedpipe-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but it didn't assign the CON output to my variable, it just printed it out (tested it in command line) `>>> output = ch(r'C:\repos\rng\rngcapture.exe 3 CON 8', shell=True) >>> Opening serial port \\.\COM3...OK 8Γ₧▀ä┌Qq Closing serial port...OK` those weird symbols in the middle came from the out put of the 1's and 0's from the device. That's what goes in file. So it came to stdout b/c I used CON like you said, but I don't really know how to capture it in the variable. the report that it finished got saved in `output`. should I use CreatenNmedPipe() to capture stdout?